# IDE: Apply property sheet to actual project settings

Tags: visual-studio-2013, propertysheet

is anybody aware of a way to apply (as in write or transfer) the settings of a Visual studio property sheet to the actual properties of the project (so they appear explicitly in .vcxproj file)?

I would like to load in a property sheet, transfer the settings to the "real" project's properties (not inherit the settings from the sheet!) so I can remove the property sheet afterward again.

Does the VS IDE allow this?
I am looking for a clickable solution, not a manual transfer.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to do this though you could program an extension or external executable (which is easy to invoke as External Tool in VS) to do this, using e.g the [Project class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.evaluation.project(v=vs.110).aspx). But it is not that trivial: what do to when conflicting properties are found? Replace them? Combine them? Moreover it sort of defeats the entire purpose of propertysheets which is having a reusable set of options for building.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the hint. This is already helpful. I don‘t see much conflict as such an extension could provide a way to select a merge strategy (similar to code merging tools). It would be nice (and make sense) to import/export property sheets to/from (user-selectable) existing project properties. That way one could also merge several sheets into a single one very conveniently, or split a more complex one. Actually this should be a core functionality of the VS IDE. :) Anyway, cheers